# Specifying a dynamic string in .property()

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to so this, but it doesnt work

```
App.FacetCheckboxView = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
    facetName: null,
    facetValue: null,
    checked: function () {
        var s = this.get('facetValue');
        var selected = this.get('controller.' + this.get('facetName'));

        return selected.contains(s);

    }.property('controller.'+ this.get('facetName') +'.@each')

})
```

If I use a static string instead in the property method argument it does work. Is there an alternative to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can define a computed property on init

```
App.FacetCheckboxView = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.defineProperty(this, 'checked', Ember.computed(function() {
         var facetValue = this.get('facetValue'),
             options = this.get('controller.' + this.get('facetName'));
         return options.contains(s);
    }).property("controller." + this.get('facetName') + ".[]", 'facetValue'));
  },
  facetName: null,
  facetValue: null

});
```

I made an example, I'm not completely sure if this is how you're using the view, but it should get you on the right road.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vopewayo/1/edit

Personally it seems like it'd be easier to just not define the value as a string, but as the collection, but I'm not sure of your exact use case.